# Android : handle fragments in a ViewPager with button

Tags: android, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I have 3 fragments in my activity, managed by a custom class which extends FragmentPagerAdapter.

My Main xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
      >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          />


  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/tabviewpager"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My activity :

```
public class RankingFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity{
....

  List fragments = new Vector();


fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Tab1Fragment.class.getName()));
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Tab2Fragment.class.getName()));
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Tab3Fragment.class.getName()));

//adapter
MyPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter =  new MyPagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.tabviewpager);

pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);

}
```

I can perfectly switch from fragments from letf to right (and right to left).

I 'd like to set buttons as listeners (in order to change displayed fragment) but I don't know how to do.

ex:
click on button1 : Fragment 1 is displayed

click on button2 : Fragment 2 is displayed

click on button3 : Fragment 3 is displayed

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is right in [the documentation for FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html)

```
    // Watch for button clicks.
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.goto_first);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Perfect ~ Thank you for your help and for the link !